# Select2 apply on @Html.DropDownList Jquery UI dialogue having small width?

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, jquery-select2, jquery-ui-dialog

I am working in MVC# and I have a `div` that I open as dialog using jQuery as shown below:

```
<div id="dialog">
    <form action="" method="post" dir="ltr">
        <div>
            @Html.DropDownList("LKP_Managers", null, " ", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control " })
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

The dialog by default has `autoOpen` set to `false`:

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false
});

function OnEdit(link) {
    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
}
```

On click it becomes viewable:

```
<input type="button" id="model.NationalID" class="btn btn-info"  onclick="javascript:OnEdit(id);" />
```

However the width that is showing is very small for the dropdown and I cannot see its values. Outside of this dialog select2 is working fine everywhere else.

I found solution a CSS solution but it applies to all dropdowns, when I only want it to apply to this specific dropdown:

```
.select2-container {
    width: 100% !important;
}

.select2-search--dropdown .select2-search__field {
    width: 98%;
}
```

Is it possible that this above CSS can be modified so that it is only implemented on my dialog dropdown **LKP_Managers**?

Comment: Hello @user802782, did my answer end up working for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom class to your dropdown and then modify your CSS to only operate on that class. This will add a class named `lkp-managers` to your `<select>` element:

```
@Html.DropDownList(
  "LKP_Managers",
  null,
  " ",
  htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control lkp-managers" }
)
```

You can then apply your CSS to just that class:

```
.select2-container.lkp-managers {
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

Your select2 definition will then need to set the [container width](https://select2.org/appearance#container-width) to `resolve` so that the width is determined from the `<select>` element's `style` attribute:

```
$('.your-select2-definition').select2({
  /* ... */
  width: 'resolve', 
})
```

Another option is to simply set the theme on your select2 instance itself and then you can modify the search field width as well as the container:

```
$('.your-select2-definition').select2({
  /* ... */
  theme: 'lkp-managers', 
})
```

with your styles as

```
.select2-container--lkp-managers {
    width: 100% !important;
}

.lkp-managers .select2-search--dropdown .select2-search__field {
    width: 98% !important;
}
```